# how to add shopping cart url under top links in magento through customer.xml

Tags: magento

I tried a lot to add shopping cart url in magento

please show me how to add shopping cart url under top links in magento through customer.xml

i did in this way.

```
<default>

        <!-- Mage_Customer -->
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="checkout"><label>Shopping Cart</label><url helper="checkout/getShoppingCartUrl"/><title>Shopping Cart</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
            <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. The technique you given is not working, i didnt see any links in the top, how can i specify the link name like shopping cart. Where i have to specify top links like shopping cart my wishlist. i have add register and login in the customer.xml. thats working. please help me

Comment: That's actually the example straight from the normal checkout XML. Please make sure to refresh your cache once you make layout changes.

Comment: you mean i have to add htis line in checkout.xml, ? i added tht xml part and cleared all cache and reports and in admin cache also cleared. No result in the top. I dont know why am alone facing this problem